# Why are cryptographic methods not vulnerable to randomized factoring algorithms?

Tags: factoring

Given that some public key cryptography systems are based on the difficulty of factoring large numbers, why are they not vulnerable to randomized factoring algorithms?

Comment: What do you mean by "randomized factoring algorithms"? Trial division?

Comment: RSA is based on factoring, most other public key crypto is not.

Comment: Question edited to reflect the fact that not all public key crypto systems are based on factoring

Comment: By "randomized factoring algorithms", I mean the probabilistic algorithms that are used for factoring large numbers which are supposedly faster than deterministic factoring algorithms

Comment: So you mean [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)? Or are you confusing probabilitstic primality testing algorithms like [Rabin-Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) with factoring algorithms?

Comment: I mean Type I and Type II probabilistic factorization algorithms (http://dlmf.nist.gov/27.19 ) that include Brent–Pollard rho algorithm, GNFS, etc. Not the primality testing algorithms

Comment: What's the meaning of "vulnerable"? Easier than brute force? Sure. Easy? No. Reason: We already consider the security based on the best known algorithms. And there is a quite a bit of a gap between suggested parameters and what would be possible - so that even some small advances wouldn't render everything insecure.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: because the size of the keys in the system are chosen so that the best "probabilist algorithms" we know for factoring (or any assumption related to the system) will fail to break it in a reasonable time.

In slightly more details, the best algorithms that we know of take subexponential time to factor a $k$-bit number (id est, something of the form $e^{c\log^\alpha k(\log\log k)^{1-\alpha}}$). They are indeed randomized algorithms, and run considerably faster than any naive method. However, for large values of $k$, performing a subexponential number of operations remains infeasible. Usually, although it's kind of an arbitrary line, a cryptosystem is considered "secure" if the best attacks take subexponential time, and "broken" if the best attacks take polynomial time (superpolynomial time $k^{\log k}$ might also be considered "somewhat broken").

The efficiency of the attack influences the choice of the keysize. For example, if the best known attack on a cryptosystem is naive bruteforce, then with keys of size $112$ bits, the best attack takes $\approx 2^{112}$ operations. If you want to get the same security level for some cryptosystem related to factorization, such as RSA, for which we know subexponential algorithm, you need a key of size $2048$ bits to compensate the fact that we know attacks far more efficient than bruteforce.

Comment: You probably should also mention that not all PK crypto depend on factoring large numbers. Mostly RSA.

Comment: Sure, hence my remark "(or any assumption related to the system)". I assumed the question was "given that some cryptosystems are based on factoring [...]", although the same observations holds for any cryptosystems for which better-than-brutefore algorithms are known (which means in particular any public key cryptosystem).